# Make table display stack on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that works fine on PC but as soon as the screen gets smaller, such as on phones, it starts to look really weird and I would like `post-image` and `post-content` to stack on smaller devices:

HTML:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-entry">
        <div class="post-image"></div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-title"><a href="#">Title</a></div>
            <div class="post-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer imperdiet ex in dolor posuere, sed congue sem bibendum. Nullam porta, diam at molestie interdum, ex diam pulvinar metus, in aliquam lacus nulla a orci.</div>
            <div class="post-date">10 November 2019</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-entry">
        <div class="post-image"></div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-title"><a href="#">Title</a></div>
            <div class="post-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer imperdiet ex in dolor posuere, sed congue sem bibendum. Nullam porta, diam at molestie interdum, ex diam pulvinar metus, in aliquam lacus nulla a orci.</div>
            <div class="post-date">9 November 2019</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-container { width: 100%; }

.post-entry {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    display: table;
}

.post-image {
    width: 190px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.post-content {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.post-title {}

.post-description {}

.post-date { opacity: 0.5; }

.post-title a { font-size: 1.2rem; }

.post-title a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5zn4e3d/). Does someone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [`media quaries`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @ZohirSalak I am familiar with media queries but not sure what the display values should be. I tried with `table-row` but that didn't work as I expected it to.

Comment: Checkout Bootstrap

Comment: @AliRasheed I cannot use Bootstrap for this since I am using a template that uses similar tags as Bootstrap which breaks ton of other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
.post-entry {
    //Anything that goes here
display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .post-entry {
    flex-direction: column
  }.post-image {
    width: 100%;
   }
}
```

I advice you to use flexboxes instead of dispaly: table.
To make this code work - delete the display: table and table-cell properties.